# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

There are several same questions that have same problem. But I cant find solution for me.

**LinQ**

```
var result = (from a in entity.TblAnalizorReadings
             group a by new { date = new DateTime(((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Year, ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Month, ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Day, ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Hour, 0, 0) } into g
             select new AnalizorPivotChartModel
             {
                  okuma_tarihi = g.Key.date,
                  Gerilim_Faz1 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz1),
                  Gerilim_Faz2 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz2),
                  Gerilim_Faz3 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz3)
              }).ToList();
```

**Model**

```
public class AnalizorPivotChartModel
{
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> okuma_tarihi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Gerilim_Faz1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Gerilim_Faz2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Gerilim_Faz3 { get; set; }
}
```

I get error message as this question title. I can write more code if its neccesary.

Thanks.

Comment: No There is no default constructor. But I can use another class that has no constructor, too.

Comment: Can this issue be connected with DateTime constructor?

Comment: I solved it. I get readings first, like this: `IEnumerable readings=entity.TblAnalizorReadings` and write above code(I get datas from readings). Is this good approach? OR any other way?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi you won't get database-side grouping this way. If performance is your concern, you should find other ways (e.g. don't create `DateTime` for grouping, you don't need it anyway)

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Why is this a bad target - to get a server-side grouping by date part of the datetime column, returning some aggregate values of the resulting groups? If EF is not ready to provide such SQL, is a stored procedure a better approach?

Comment: Instead of writing `Nullable<decimal>` it's shorter to write `decimal?` instead in C#. Just a tip.

Comment: Its created by db_context_generator. I Just copy-paste :)

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov you can do a server-side grouping by date part of `datetime` column more or less easily with anonymous type. But that has nothing to do with OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = entity.TblAnalizorReadings
    .GroupBy(a =>
        new {
            ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Year,
            ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Month,
            ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Day,
            ((DateTime)a.okuma_tarihi).Hour
        },
        (k, g) => new {
            okuma_tarihi = k,
            Gerilim_Faz1 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz1),
            Gerilim_Faz2 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz2),
            Gerilim_Faz3 = g.Max(x => x.Gerilim_Faz3)
        })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(g => new AnalizorPivotChartModel
         {
              okuma_tarihi = new DateTime(okuma_tarihi.Year, okuma_tarihi.Month, okuma_tarihi.Day, okuma_tarihi.Hour, 0, 0),
              Gerilim_Faz1 = g.Gerilim_Faz1,
              Gerilim_Faz2 = g.Gerilim_Faz2,
              Gerilim_Faz3 = g.Gerilim_Faz3
          })
    .ToList();
```