# linq equivalent for counting records by date and hours

Tags: c#, linq

i have a sql query, but what would be the equivalent for this in c# LINQ ?

```
SELECT CAST(DateAdded as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,DateAdded) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM [TABLE1].[dbo].[PartValues]

GROUP BY CAST(DateAdded as date),
       DATEPART(hour,DateAdded)
       Order by ForDate Desc,
       OnHour Desc
```

The idea is to count records by date and hour- like this :

```
ForDate OnHour  Totals
2016-05-25  9   36
2016-05-25  8   60
2016-05-25  7   70
2016-05-25  6   12
2016-05-24  21  24
2016-05-24  20  72
2016-05-24  19  24
2016-05-24  14  120
```

Comment: What is the type of `DateAdded`? datetime?

Comment: Why are you trying to turn a SQL statement into a LINQ statement? Are you trying to use LINQ TO SQL or just looking for the logic? Where are your c# objects? Are you trying to call this SQL statement from a c# application? Please be more clear.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I would hope so. Specification says it can be any of the date or time types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) to extract the date part of the `DateAdded` column. This code should work:

```
var result = context.PartValues
    .GroupBy(x => new
    {
        Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateAdded), //Extract Date only (time part is 0)
        Hour = x.DateAdded.Hour
    }).Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Date,
        g.Key.Hour,
        Total = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
var results = context.partValues.GroupBy(r =>
   new DateTime(r.dateAdded.Year,
                r.dateAdded.Month,
                r.dateAdded.Day,
                r.dateAdded.Hour, 0, 0),
   (d, r) => new { date = d, totals = r.Count() });
```

Comment: I think that OP is using LINQ to SQL and I don't think that LINQ allows the construction of `DateTime` within the query in this case.

Comment: However, you can construct an anonymous type inside the query, e.g., `new {r.dateAdded.Year, r.dateAdded.Month, r.dateAdded.Day,r.dateAdded.Hour}`. That would work.

Comment: Do you have a source on not being able to instantiate new datetime? I can't find any so far.

Comment: Take a look at this (the first comment): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217956/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155019/only-parameterless-constructors-and-initializers-are-supported-in-linq-to-entiti

Comment: You are saying that new DateTime() will not work and new { date = new DateTime() } will?

Comment: No, I am saying that `new {r.dateAdded.Year ...` will work. `new { date = new DateTime() }` might not throw an exception, but it is meaningless.